# Getting just the number of rows using Mysqli and PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I want to get how many (possibly 0) times a particular number occurs in a particular column. I set the number in $contact_client_ID then do the SELECT query below.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM t_contacts WHERE contact_client_ID ='$contact_client_ID'";
$result=(mysqli_query($link, $sql));
$count_result= mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo "contact client ID $contact_client_ID xxxxx $count_result";
```

Instead of $count_result containing the number I want, it contains a result made up of the number I want and the contact_client_ID joined together and the result doesn't seem to be usable as a number in any following code.

So, if $contact_client_ID = 50 and there are 2 occurrences of it in the table, the output I get is:

***contact client ID 50 xxxxx 250***

I've looked at the manuals and examples all over the place (including here) and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: SELECT contact_client_ID, count(*)  FROM ... GROUP BY contact_client_ID

Comment: You must have an `echo 50` somewhere in your code that displays the stray 50.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `(mysqli_query($link, $sql));` in parenthesis (brackets)?

Comment: I'll try that Roy.
There are no other echo statements Salman.
Script47 - not sure - I've tended to re-use code that has worked for me - would this affect the outcome?

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways of doing this, more precisely you have the option, to either do the count in PHP, or make your SQL server do the counting and just return the number:

1. Do it in PHP:

What it requires is: - fetch all data; -make a counter variable; - loop trough the data, for each loop increase counter +1

For small tables you can use PHP, for bigger ones I advice doing it on the SQL, since for PHP to count it it must fetch all the data.

```
$counter=0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM t_contacts WHERE contact_client_ID ='$contact_client_ID";
$res = $con->query($query);
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
$counter++;
}
```

2. Do it in SQL

Now the smarter way would be to do it on the SQL server ,as it would handle the load better;

I would say what /u/Adaleni wrote is pretty close to what I would use:

```
$sql = "SELECT count(contact_client_ID) as total FROM t_contacts WHERE contact_client_ID ='$contact_client_ID'";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $sql);
$count_result= mysqli_fetch_row(result);
echo "contact client ID $contact_client_ID xxxxx $count_result[0]['total']";
```

Lets just describe what he does:

1. we use COUNT() function in SQL, this makes the server count the number of occurances of contact_client_ID and then make (in the result) a new variable called "total"
2. we execute the query and get the result
3. We use mysqli_fetch_rowm this function gets the result row as an enumerated array
4. then we access that array (as we know its only 1 item, we accessed index 0) and we print the variable total which we made in step 1 -  $count_result[0]['total']

Comment: Thanks for this - after a brief lay down and a cup of tea I shall try them; you PHP solution was in my head anyway as earlier in the code I have to step through these occurrences. BUT, I still don't know why mysqli_num_rows isn't working as (it seems) to be described in the documentation.

Comment: @MarshalAnderson Can't really tell you, but in my exp with old and tested functions, like this one is most like fault of your code and not the function (I dont want to sound harsh, just my exp).
P.s. If this answer helped you you can upvote it, or mark it as accepted answer :)

Comment: I know it's my code - damn, I started with 6502 machine code in 1979 and I know that if it doesn't work it has to be my fault :o) But I've never struggled so much with documentation. <sigh>  Anyway - thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

/* Select queries return a resultset */

```
 if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM t_contacts WHERE contact_client_ID ='$contact_client_ID")) {
printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);
```

Comment: Done that - the result is still the number of rows and client ID together :(

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I'm developing this on a free DB with 000webhost.com

Comment: Oh nice...am working on 000webhost.com too
Your DB is Phpmyadmin then.
So what you do....run the sql query in phpmyadmin first , to confirm your answer

Comment: I've not used printf - what does the %d do?

Comment: Try the code first...let me know if you are getting any errors.

Comment: %d is an argument that is treated as an integer.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /storage/ssd1/889/5542889/public_html/live_remove_contact_confirm.php on line 57

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in /storage/ssd1/889/5542889/public_html/live_remove_contact_confirm.php:57 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd1/889/5542889/public_html/live_remove_contact_confirm.php on line 57

Comment: OK - I can do this another way earlier - the code actually deletes an entry and I can use the "while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_result)) {" structure to count the number or rows before deletion and use that as my variable. I guess my frustration (and possibly yours) is that it's difficult to get the overview of these languages I need. All the references and examples say mysqli_num_rows($result) returns the number of rows - but that's not working for me despite duplicating the examples. I'm missing something basic and I don't know where to find it :(

Comment: In your case $mysqli will be $link.